# Using an include statement as the default value

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I am creating a helm chart in which I want to specify a default for a value using a template function. Specifically I want to either use the override value image.name, or default to the template function chart.name:

```
{{ .Values.image.name | default include chart.name . }}
```

But when linting the chart I have the following error:

```
[ERROR] templates/: render error in "chart/templates/deployment.yaml": template: chart/templates/deployment.yaml:22:81: executing "chart/templates/deployment.yaml" at <include>: wrong number of args for include: want 2 got 0
```

Is it possible to use an included template function as the default value? Or can I only use literals?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can. Just enclose your include statement in parentheses:

`{{ .Values.image.name | default (include "chart.name" .)}}`

Please see [using the default function](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/master/docs/chart_template_guide/functions_and_pipelines.md#using-the-default-function)

Comment: I was searching this and saw the answer. Thank you @edbighead